# Which is the most authentic english translation of Manu Smriti?

Tags: manu-smriti, resource, manu

Which is the most authentic translation of Manu Smriti preferably literal word to word one?

Comment: Literal and authentic often are are odds with each other. Do you want to know what Manu said, or what Manu meant? The most revered commentary on the Manu Smriti is the one by Medhatithi and there is an English translation by Ganganath Jha which can be considered the most authentic. There is a scanned version here. https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.281746    By modern western academic standards, Patrick Olivelle's translation is respected in American circles. "Authentic" is a subjective term.

Comment: @hashable It is upto the reader to see what Manu meant...Anyways Thanks for ur comment its really helpful..u should answer this question :)